# Does using rxJava for form validation make sense

Tags: android, rx-java2

I have a screen in my Android app that has several input fields that need to be validated before the the Save button can be used. The save button is always enabled but will not do anything if any of the input fields do not have any valid data.

There are two approaches I can think of. One is the traditional way of validating each field when each of them loses focus and then set a member flag that indicates whether the field is good or bad. The save button would check the flags on all of the fields and then ignore the click event if any of them indicate not being valid.

The other approach is to use rxJava and somehow feed the text from the input fields into a stream when the field loses focus. It isn't clear to me though how to implement this approach with multiple fields. Does an rxJava approach even make sense? Or is it overkill?

Comment: you say that `validating each field when each of them loses focus` and then `use rxJava ... when the field loses focus` so, this sounds like the same approach to me, aren't you perhaps just over-complicating this :)

Comment: I agree with @a_local_nobody on user or developer point of view.It may depends on client's requirement

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It's possible good variant. You can have for each EditText own validator. Like:

```
interface InputValidator : TextWatcher {
  fun isValid(): Boolean
}
```

with default possible implementation:

```
class SimpleInputValidator(private val threshold: Int = 1) : InputValidator {

  private var isValid = false
  override fun isValid(): Boolean {
    return isValid
  }

  override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
    isValid = s?.length?: 0 >  threshold
  }

  override fun beforeTextChanged(
    s: CharSequence?,
    start: Int,
    count: Int,
    after: Int
  ) { }

  override fun onTextChanged(
    s: CharSequence?,
    start: Int,
    before: Int,
    count: Int
  ) { }
}
```

and in your Fragment/Activity using Jake Wharton's rxbinding3 library:

```
class MyFragment : Fragment() {

  private val editText1: EditText
  private val editText2: EditText

  private val validator1: InputValidator = SimpleInputValidator(10)
  private val validator2: InputValidator = SimpleInputValidator(20)

  private var isMainButtonValid = false

  override fun onViewCreated(
    view: View,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
  ) {

    editText1.addTextChangedListener(validator1)
    editText2.addTextChangedListener(validator2)

    editText1.afterTextChangeEvents().subcribe {
      validateMainButton()
    }
    editText2.afterTextChangeEvents().subcribe {
      validateMainButton()
    }
  }

  private fun validateMainButton() {
    isMainButtonValid = validator1.isValid() && validator2.isValid()
  }
}
```

Comment: To be honest, this looks like overkill and doesn't seem to be any less code than the traditional solution that doesn't use rxJava. So I really see no benefit with this solution. Or am I missing the point?